# eval()'d code on line xx

Tags: php

i have this code , i want to convert the get(title) to variable , its correctly working , for example i have variable 'news , sport, program ' , my problem is that when someone is changing the title="news" to title=new , and i dont have the new variable how i can control it when the user change the title ;
this will appear an error that the variable undefined and eval()'d code on line xx error

```
if(isset($_GET['title']))
    $title=stripslashes($_GET['title']);
else
   $title="news";

$trimed=trim(strtolower($title));
$variable="$".str_replace(" ","_",$trimed);
$title=eval('return '.$variable.';');  

if(!isset($title))
    $title=$$title;
```

thank you for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do like this:

```
$nameOfVar = 'return' . $variable;
$title = $nameOfVar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `${}` syntax and replace:

```
$title = eval('return '. $variable.';');
```

With:

```
$title = ${'return '. $variable};
```